# matlab finding pixelwise median for a series of images

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, pixel

I am trying to find the pixelwise median value for a series of dicom images in matlab.

My array of images has the size (256, 256, 20) - with the 20 being the 20 images.

I'm new to matlab and think I am doing something horribly wrong since my code has been running for over an hour. Here it is:

```
med_img = []
for k = 1:size(Im_Orig,1)
    for i = 1:size(Im_Orig,2)
        med_img(k,i) = median(Im_Orig(k,i,:))
    end
end
```

I know nested for loops are to be avoided when possible, but I can't figure out a better solution or find a good function anywhere online.

Any help would be awesome!

Comment: Just to clarify, you're trying to find the median for the 20 images in this case correct?

Comment: I am trying to find the median value for each pixel. I will then be finding the image that is closest to this pixelwise median 'image'. It is pretty much finding the median image.

Comment: Suppress the output by adding a semi-colon to the line  `med_img(k,i) = median(Im_Orig(k,i,:));` should do the trick. Also preallocating the size of the array may also help the speed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Finding the Median Image Among a Set of Images

This should take the median along the 3rd dimension which corresponds to the median between each of the corresponding pixels.

[image: Taking the Median Along the 3rd Dimension]

### Method 1: Taking Median Along the Third Dimension:

```
%Random data simulating image%
Image = round(255.*rand(256,256,20));

Dimension = 3;
Median_Image = median(Image,Dimension);
```

### Method 2: Using for Loops and Taking the Median of Each Downwards Vector/Column:

```
%Random data simulating image%
Image = round(255.*rand(256,256,20));

%Grabbing dimensions of multi-image array%
[Image_Height,Image_Width,Number_Of_Images] = size(Image);


Median_Image = zeros(Image_Height,Image_Width);

for Row = 1: Image_Height
   for Column = 1: Image_Width 
    
Median_Image(Row,Column) = median(Image(Row,Column,:),'all');
       
    
   end
end
```

**Ran using MATLAB R2019b**

Comment: Thank you so much! Both methods worked perfectly and ran really quickly.